# Verificar se objeto chegou pela API dos correios

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api

estou fazendo uso da API dos correios. Consegui rastrear objetos perfeitamente. Porém ainda resta uma ação para completar o ratreamento: verificar se o objeto chegou.

Meu desejo era que a API executasse um método da minha aplicação e settase um atributo para assinalar que o objeto chegou. Alguém sabe se a API dos correios da suporte para tal?

Comment: Que ela executa um método seu, não. Possivelmente há como verificar o status do objeto, então bastaria que você fizesse um processo que verificasse este status e alterasse o atributo. Fazer uso de CRON seria uma boa.

Comment: O Correios não fornece API para esta verificação, porém fornece um WS SOAP descrito neste manual: [https://m.correios.com.br/a-a-z/pdf/rastreamento-de-objetos/manual_rastreamentoobjetosws.pdf](https://m.correios.com.br/a-a-z/pdf/rastreamento-de-objetos/manual_rastreamentoobjetosws.pdf)

Comment: Sim, é possível verificar se um determinado chegou utilizando SOAP do Correios, porém é necessário uma gambiarra (caso você esteja utilizando o código no front-end), pois o navegador irá bloquear o acesso devido CORS.